# Use the MAX function with no-digital contents in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on a quality control table and I just want to use `MAX` function to do some statistical calculation. For example:

```
Apple1 | weight | 1.25
Apple1 | width  | 0.6
Apple1 | height | 0.8
Apple2 | weight | 1.3
Apple2 | width  | 0.75
Apple2 | height | DIV/0
Apple3 | weight | 1.1
Apple3 | width  | DIV/0
Apple3 | height | 0.6
```

If I want want to see the haviest apple in these 3, then here is my code:

```
=MAX(IF(Data!$B:$B=MSA!E7;Data!$C:Data!$C))
```

I compare the title of each test and find the Max test's result for each rest. But I meet always the N/A error. It seems that the results that I've put into the table are not all "number" that `MAX` can compare. there is `DIV/0` in some cells.

I've tried to change the Attributes of the result column like:

```
=MAX(1*Data!$C:$C)
=MAX(--Data!$C:$C)
```

But it doesn't work either. I don't know how to avoid to count on the non-digital cells and only do the `MAX` with the numbers.

Comment: I don't think it's the `MAX` formula causing the error - it's the `#N/A` and `#DIV/0` errors.  If you have a formula such as `=A1/B1` and `B1` is 0 then you need to rewrite the formula as `=IF(B1=0,0,A1/B1)` or `=IFERROR(A1/B1,0)`.  The `#N/A` error occurs if you're using formula such as `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` and it's not finding a result - change this so it returns a non-error result:  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,$F$1:$G$3,2,FALSE),0)`

Comment: Yes I agree, I've tested this formula by chosing all the "correct" cells who contain only numbers, and `MAX`works well. But can I just "avoid" the `DIV/0` cells and compare the numbers? Because in the report, the `DIV/0` exists already in the result column and I just want to find the biggest and the smallest results.

Comment: You could try `=MAX(IFERROR(D1:D4,0))` entering it as an array formula (Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`) and update the range to reflect yours.  All errors should be converted to 0 values.

Comment: Sorry I don't quiet understand, how can I use `=MAX(IFERROR(D1:D4,0))` to compare the value in D1 to D4? This code can just remove the errors I think? And how can complete this code?

Comment: The formula looks at each of the cells in the range D1:D4.  If any value is an error it converts that value to 0.  It then finds the maximum value in the range - with all errors converted to 0.  The values `2`, `0.333`,`#DIV/0` and `#N/A` will return the value `2`.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! And where can I put my criteria inside? Because I have to select some cells according to the criteria and find the largest seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can be asked to ignore errors while producing a [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db). A [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) with a *k* of 1 is a [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333).

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (Data!Y8254:Data!Y8716)/(Data!T8254:Data!T8716=MSA!E7), 1)
'might better like this; you do not need to double up the worksheet in a range
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (Data!Y8254:Y8716)/(Data!T8254:T8716=MSA!E7), 1)
```

Comment: Or you can do that. :)

Comment: Thanks to you and @DarrenBartrup-Cook ! This `AGGREGATE` function is really practical!

Comment: And @Jeeped sorry I still have a question, that in the brackets, `(Data!Y8254:Data!Y8716)/(Data!T8254:Data!T8716=MSA!E7)` can it select the cells in column `Y8254:Y8716` which correspond my criteria in `MSA!E7`? I think the formula will chose the lagests result in `Y8254:Y8716` and in `T8254:T8716` separately? Actually, in `T` column are the criterias and in `Y` column are the results so I'd like to select the "important" tests and do the statistical work.

Comment: OK... so the **6** tells AGGREGATE to ignore errors. If there are any errors in Data!Y8254:Y8716 they will be ignored. If Data!T8254:T8716 doe not match MSA!E7 then it becomes False which Excel interprets as a zero. Since Data!Y8254:Y8716 is the numerator and Data!T8254:T8716=MSA!E7 is the denominator in the division, anything that does not match will produce a `#DIV/0!` error and will be ignored as well. So you are ignoring all of hte errors in Data!Y8254:Y8716 and all of the non-matches in Data!T8254:T8716.

Comment: Sorry I met another problem, that I use `=AGREGAT(14;6;((Data!$Y:$Y)/(Data!$S:$S=MSA!B$7)*(Data!$P:$P=MSA!T$5)));1)-AGREGAT(15;6;((Data!$Y:$Y)/(Data!$S:$S=MSA!B$7)*(Data!$P:$P=MSA!T$5)));2)` to calculate the largest difference in this group if samples. But the smallest one (or the lagest one in the group of negative data) are 0. Does that because of the DIV/0 in the column?

Comment: And I've tried with 3, 4, 5 on the second ref, but the answer is still the same.

Comment: You shouldn't use full column references with AGGREGATE. The error/no error should be closer to `=AGREGAT(14;6;(Data!$Y:$Y)/((Data!$S:$S=MSA!B$7)*(Data!$P:$P=MSA!T$5)));1)` note the change in brackets to isolate zero as the denominator.